# Are array/list lengths and string hashcodes memoized?

Tags: c#

Does anyone happen to know if, in .NET (4.0, if it matters), the Length property of an array, or the Count property of a `List<T>` is stored after it's been calculated, until the array/list is changed?

I ask because a record linkage program I'm working on is already horrifically complex enough as it is, and I'd rather not add another O(n) on top of things if I can help it.

Along similar lines, is the hashcode of an instantiated System.String memoized? Looking at it through the debugger, I can see that `List<T>` has a private _size member that *could* be where Count gets its value, but I see nothing for int[] or string indicating that they store it anywhere.

I can see the size vs. speed tradeoff, but can anyone tell me for sure if there are backing fields that hold these? For example, since in C#, strings are immutable, wouldn't it make sense to calculate the hashcode the first time `GetHashCode` is called, and just store it for every later use?

Comment: Perhaps helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717801/is-string-length-in-c-sharp-net-instant-variable

Comment: I'd like to give someone the answer, but I'd still like to know whether GetHashCode()'s value is memoized or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reflector the implementation of `List<T>.Count` is:

```
public int Count
{
  get
  {
    return this._size;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure about `Array.Length`. The code for it is:

```
public int Length 
{ 
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success), 
    SecuritySafeCritical, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)] 
    get; 
}
```

Comment: For single-dimensional arrays, there is actually an IL OpCode that pushes an array's length directly onto the execution stack, so the length of the array is stored at a primitive level.

Answer (score 2):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=VS.100).aspx

> The List class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It
>   implements the IList generic interface using an array whose size is
>   dynamically increased as required.

This would suggest, the Length property is known at any point in time and need not be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

From the [.NET Reference Source Code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx), I looked at List. It holds a variable _size. Therefore whenever an item is added or removed it increments or decrements the size. So it is not really calculated and is always stored in a variable.